# Django rest framework - pass additional arguments to validate_foo

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

As per DRF documentation [DRF Validators](http://djangorestframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

My method should be like

```
def validate_title(self, value):
    """
    Check that the blog post is about Django.
    """
    if 'django' not in value.lower():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
    return value
```

I want to pass an additional argument to `validate_title`, so it should look like

Here id is some value that I want to pass while calling the Serializer.

```
def validate_title(self, value, id):
        """
        Check that the blog post is about Django.
        """
        # Use <id> here
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
        return value
```

I am not able to understand how to achieve this, any help?

Comment: Where is that id value coming from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated.

Comment: Still not clear enough to get help

Comment: use the validate method for object level validation

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. To answer your question, I guess you want to pass extra parameters to validate_{} method. You can always use *args and **kwargs to pass extra parameters to custom model validate method. Then extract values from the above parameters which should help you get the parameter.

```
def validate_title(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use context. Pass context to serializer constructor (`Serializer(data=data, context={'id': id}`), then get id from context in valid_title method(`id = self.context.get('id')`).